# RODBC and MYSQL procedure parameters

Tags: mysql, r, rodbc

I would like to repeatedly query a `MySQL` database from inside `R` with the `RODBC` package.
I have a `MySQL procedure` that I normally call like this:

```
CALL`myDB`.`myProc`(x,y)
```

If I use RODBC, how can I pass x and y to the function efficiently?
Am I stuck using paste() as in:

```
sqlQuery(channel,paste("CALL`myDB`.`myProc`(",x,",",y,")"))
```

Comment: For substituting specific values, sprintf() might be a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use paste just like that, except consider using sep=""